# uninitialized constant Capistrano (NameError)

Tags: rvm, rvm-capistrano

rvm 1.14.5, rvm-capistrano (1.2.2) and capistrano (2.12.0)
My Gemfile is :

```
group :development, :test do
   gem 'rvm-capistrano'
   gem 'capistrano'
end
```

When I try to start passenger, I keep seeing this error :

```
[ pid=4691 thr=76294140 file=utils.rb:176 time=2012-07-04 11:37:06.179 ]: *** Exception NameError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (uninitialized constant Capistrano) (process 4691, thread #<Thread:0x9184ff8>):
from /home/ved/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rvm-capistrano-1.2.2/lib/rvm/capistrano.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ved/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
from /home/ved/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `rescue in block in require'
from /home/ved/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
from /home/ved/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /home/ved/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/ved/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
from /home/ved/rails_projects/grabber/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ved/rails_projects/grabber/config/environment.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/ved/rails_projects/grabber/config/environment.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from config.ru:3:in `require'
from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just taking a stab here, but make sure that you are excluding the development and test group when your bundle is installed.

bundle install --without test development

It sounds like for some reason your application is trying to load rvm-capistrano.